# Setting the permissions of a file correctly after moving

Tags: c#, permissions, file-permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, handle

I transfer a file from one location to another. The problem is when I transfer the file to the new location, the permissions on the file are what they were before I moved it.

Suppose I have User "A", User "B" folder "F1" and folder "F2"

The user "A" has access to files in the folder "F1". I execute this code in c# to move my files from folder "F1" to folder "F2"

```
File.Move(filePath, copyPath2);
```

In the folder "F2" the user "A" did not has access to the files. When I look at the permission after the move, all the permissions on the files in the "F2" folder, are set the permission from "F1" folder.

Is there a way when I move files from a location to another in c#, to remove permissions?

I am in windows 2008 r2 and the reason i try to do that is writed on this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/360107/handle-lock-by-iis-with-arr-module-how-release-it-without-recycle-the-applicatio). It's a problem with ARR modules and IIS file handle

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread from MSDN forums:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/netfxbcl/thread/51694aec-90d2-4d90-8e9a-af0ab91cc610

Here's a simple adaption to your question:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(copyPath2);
FileSecurity fileSecurity = fileInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Audit);     
fileSecurity.SetAuditRuleProtection(false, false);
fileInfo.SetAccessControl(fileSecurity);
```